# Unable to modify rich text field in custom list which is customized with InfoPath.

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

So I've a rich text field in custom list which is customized with InfoPath. I'm unable to modify this field in quick edit view for existing records. I'm able to do this for lists which are not customized with InfoPath. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: How did you customize the field in the InfoPath form? Per my test, the Rich Text field works in the Quick Edit. What have you done in the form? Please provide more information about your form.

Comment: Customized to use the InfoPath form to save the records to the list. Nothing much. There are other customization like having default values and rules for some controls.

Comment: If you create a simple InfoPath form for the list, without any rules or code, does the Quick Edit work?